# Thymeleaf, not getting the title and input in the same line

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here is the Thymeleaf code for taking user inputs and then put it into their respective square boxes, the title and user input is coming in different lines, how can I make it in single line.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->


    <style>
      body {
         margin: 0;
         font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      }

         .squares {

  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
      .icon1,
.icon2 {
       width: 2%;
  height: 50%;
    background: #F5F8FA;
}


 .icon1 {
        margin-right: 10%;
        border-style: ridge;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
    }

      p {
         margin: 0;
      }




      .pagewidth {
         width: 1140px;
         margin: auto;
      }

      .blue-box {
         background: #bbd2ed;
         padding: 15px;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
         box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
      }

      .blue-box-new {
         background: #90EE90;
         padding: 15px;
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
         box-sizing: border-box;

      }

      .row {
         display: inline-block;
         width: 100%;
      }

      .fields {
         float: left;
         width: 90%;
      }

      .first-label {
         float: left;
         width: 10%;
         text-align: right;
      }

      .field {
         float: left;
      }

      .label {
         font-size: 7px;
         margin-left: 5px;
         margin-right: 5px;
         align= right;
          padding-right: 5px;
      }

      .input {
         border: none;
         width: 22px;
         height: 22px;
         padding: 0;
         text-align: center;
      }

      .input::placeholder {
         color: red;
         text-align: center;
      }

      .right {
         float: right;
      }

      .sign {
         background: #fff;
         width: 220px;
         height: 70px;
         padding-top: 55px;
         box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      .sign span {
         color: grey;
         font-size: 10px;
         display: block;
         text-align: center;
      }

      .two-col {
         display: table;
         width: 100%;
      }

      .left-col {
         display: table-cell;
         vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .right-col {
         display: table-cell;
         vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .two-col .first-label {
         width: 12.5%;
      }

      .two-col .fields {
         width: 87.5%;
      }

      .sec-title {
         text-align: center;
         margin: 0;
         font-size: 14px;
         text-decoration: underline;
         color: #ef4d37;
      }

      .green-box {
         background: #bae5fa;
         padding: 15px;
      }
      .boxed {
  border: 1px solid green ;
  width: 2%;
  height: 10%;
    background: #F5F8FA;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
}

.ex1 {

  padding-right: 100px;
  font-size:8px;
}
.wrap {
border: 1px solid green ;
 width: 10px;
         height: 5px;
         padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    background: #F5F8FA;


}
.wrap1 {
border: 1px solid green ;
font-size: 7px;
padding-right: 5px;
width: 8px;
height: 5px;
text-align: right;
background: #F5F8FA;

}
.wrap3{
padding-right: 15px;
}

.wrap2 {
border: 1px solid green ;
font-size: 7px;
padding-right: 5px;
width: 10px;
height: 15px;
text-align: right;
background: #F5F8FA;

}
.here{
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}
   </style>

</head>
<body>

<!--<td th:text="${orderItems}"/> -->

<tbody class="blue-box">
<p style="font-size:10px; "><center><u>BANK USE SECTION</u></center></p>
<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">

    <div class="row">

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Sourcing Channel</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.sourcingChannel}"></td>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Branch</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.branch}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:5px; ">DST</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dst}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:5px; ">DSA</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dsa}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:5px; ">PBK</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.pbk}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:5px; ">Web</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.web}"></td>

        <th style="font-size:5px; ">ReferSales</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.referSales}"></td>

        <th th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(item.otherChannleSpecify)}">
            <th style="font-size:5px; ">Other Channel (Specify)</th>
            <body  th:with="someVariable=${#lists.size(item.otherChannleSpecify)}">
                <th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, someVariable - 1)}">
                    <td class="wrap2" th:text="${item.otherChannleSpecify[i]}"></td>
                </th:block>
                <th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, someVariable - 1)}">
        <td class="wrap1"></td>

        </th:block>
            </body>

        </th>

       <!-- <th style="font-size:5px; ">Other Channel (Specify)</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.otherChannleSpecify[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.otherChannleSpecify[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.otherChannleSpecify[2]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.otherChannleSpecify[3]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/> -->


    </div >
    <td class="here"></td>
</tr>

<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Source 1</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source1[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source1[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source1[2]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source1[3]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Source 2</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source2[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source2[1]}"></td>

        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>


        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Source 3</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source3[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source3[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Source 4</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source4[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.source4[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Branch Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.branchCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.branchCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>


        <th style="font-size:7px; ">LTS/CRMN No</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.ltsCrnmNum[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.ltsCrnmNum[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>


        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Sales Promo Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.salesPromoCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.salesPromoCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
    </div>
</tr>
<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">SM Emp Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.smEmpCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.smEmpCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">SE Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.seCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.seCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">DSA/DDSA Name</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dsaDdsaName[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dsaDdsaName[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
    </div>
</tr>


<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">ASM Emp Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.asmEmpCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.asmEmpCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">TSE Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.tseCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.tseCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>


        <th style="font-size:7px; ">DSA /DDSA Vendor Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dsaDdsaVendorCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dsaDdsaVendorCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Dealer SE Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dealerSeCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.dealerSeCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>

        <th style="font-size:7px; ">RSM Emp Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.rsmEmpCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.rsmEmpCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>


        <th style="font-size:7px; ">TL Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.tlCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.tlCode[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Village Name</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.villageName[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.villageName[1]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
        <td class="wrap1"/>
    </div>
</tr>

<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">RBI Code</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.rbiCode[0]}"></td>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.rbiCode[1]}"></td>

    </div>
</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody class="blue-box-new">

<p style="font-size:10px; "><center><u><b>CUSTOMER SECTION (to be filled by the Customer in CAPITAL LETTERS)</b></u></center></p>
<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>


        <div th:if="${not #lists.isEmpty(item.branchDate)}">
            <div th:with="someVariable=${#lists.size(item.branchDate)}">
                <!--<h1 th:text="${someVariable}"></h1> -->
                <td class="ex1">I wish to apply for below ticked (a) loan and request you to process the loan application as per details provided in the form</td>

                <td class="label" >Branch</td>
                <th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, someVariable - 1)}">
                    <td class="wrap2" th:text="${item.branchDate[i]}"></td>
                </th:block>

                <th th:if="${someVariable<4}"> </th>
                     <th:block th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, someVariable - 1)}">
                         <td class="wrap1"></td>

                    </th:block>




            </div>
        </div>


        <div th:if="${#lists.size(item.branchDate)==0}">
            <div>Welcome, Guest</div>
        </div>
        <div th:if="${#lists.size(item.branchDate)<0}">
            <div>Hi, User</div>
        </div>


    </div>

</tr>
<tr th:each="item, iterStat: ${orderItems}">
    <div>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.personal}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Personal</th>

        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.business}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Business</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.largeTicketBusiness}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Large Ticket Business</th>
        <td class="wrap1" th:text="${item.selfEmployedBusiness}"></td>
        <th style="font-size:7px; ">Self Employed Professional</th>
    </div>
</tr>
</tbody>





</body>
</html>
```

[I want the out to be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Id05t.png)

[But I am getting like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdSdo.png)

I am new to Thymeleaf.

Comment: Please focus on one _specific_ problem. Please provide a [mre] for that. Remove every piece of code which is not _directly relevant_ to that problem. Make it as easy as possible for the community to recreate your problem for themselves. Right now, you are showing us a relatively large code dump.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.